# reverse a list of generic type

Tags: java, reinventing-the-wheel, collections

> Q: Given a list, reverse the order of its elements (don't use
>   collections).

Here is my solution:

```
public static <T> void reverse(List<T> list) {
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        T t;
        t = list.get(0);
        list.remove(0);
        reverse(list);
        list.add(t);
    }
}
```

1. I want to know if this is an efficient way of reversing a list
2. Is this working for every list as input?

Comment: You could compare performance of this against [Collection.reverse](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#LC421). My guess is Collection.reverse would be faster

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it's unclear what the scope of restrictions is concerning the use of collections.

Comment: @dustytrash That's explicitly disallowed.

Comment: @dfhwze Likely the [Collections API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework), what's unclear?

Comment: @Mast I'd say it's not entirely clear whether it's the Collections API, or just collections in general.

Comment: It's a while since I did Java, but I'm pretty sure `List<T>` is part of Collections.

Comment: Wow, moments like this make Python so much prettier... `mylist = mylist[::-1]`

Comment: @Gloweye that isn't in-place, and I'd take a method call with the word `reverse` in it over that any day ;)

Comment: list.reversed() works just as well, but the question disallows builtin methods, and reverse slicing isn't a method. (and for pure iteration, slicing may even be faster...I'd have to check.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java doesn't handle recursion very well. And by not very well I mean it should be avoided almost every time where you cannot limit the depth to something small. To show you how bad it is let's take a look at this simple program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int n = 0; n < 100_000; n+=100) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        reverse(list);
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

At some point in the output we can see this:

```
17800
17900
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at slowness.SlowApp.reverse(SlowApp.java:24)
at slowness.SlowApp.reverse(SlowApp.java:24)
```

This means that on my machine with default settings I can't even handle a list of 18000 integers. Any list bigger than that just crashes the program.

Is it possible to do it without recursion then?

This has proven a little trickier than I expected when I started writing this answer.

I was thinking of 2 possible approaches.

One is to always update the list in place. Just take the last element from the list and insert it into the correct spot (insert at 0, next insert at 1, next ...). Since we don't know which kind of List we are working with this could be a really expensive operation.

The other approach is to first take a copy of all the elements. Then clear the input list. Reverse the copied elements and insert them back into the input list. The main advantage here is that we can copy them into an array which allows O(1) access to each element even for updating them.

An example implementation is then:

```
public static <T> void reverse2(List<T> list) {
    T[] array = (T[]) list.toArray();

    list.clear();

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length/2; i++) {
        T temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[array.length - i-1];
        array[array.length-i-1] = temp;
    }

    for(T item : array) {
        list.add(item);
    }
}
```

This implementation has no issue with a List of a million Integers.

Edit: just inserting backwards was too obvious after I tried to use list.addAll(aray) which didn't work (needs collection, not an array). I'll leave the current implementation as-is in my answer.

Note that this also isn't the most efficient way. I highly advise you to look at the implementation of the internal Collection.reverse to see a better way.

Comment: Argh, done it again. I keep forgetting `List` is an interface in Java... @CristianIacob this should probably be the answer, because it isn't wrong and is more general (I'll address that first part in mine presently...)

Comment: Note that the OP did specify that they don't want to use other collections.

Comment: @VisualMelon I interpreted that as "don't use collections.reverse, implement it yourself". Otherwise you couldn't even use *add* or *remove*

Comment: Is `for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { list.add(array[i]); }` (backwards iteration + add) different than the 1.5x iteration?

Comment: why do you bother reversing the array, rather than just inserting in reverse order?

Comment: @IvanGarcíaTopete it is obviously better ... but both are O(n) time complexity so it doesn't make too much of a difference. My example implementation is clearly far from perfect. Note that the collectitons.reverse does even better :)

Comment: Just tested it with a list with 1,000,000 items a 1,000,000 times with each method, there's just 1 second of difference so yes, it doesn't make too much of a difference

Answer (score 10):

No and no. This is a very inefficient way to reverse, for example, a dynamic array based list (it's a different story with a linked list). With a dynamic array based (e.g. `ArrayList`) The `remove(0)` operation will require moving every other element in the list (linear in the length), so the whole method is quadratic in the total length of the list. It also requires a linear number of stack frames, which are actually pretty expensive and if you ask for too many the program will crash, which means this method will not work for long lists.

An efficient solution would work in linear time with a constant space requirement.

---

When thinking about inputs, it's important to also consider `null` as a possible input. The deficient spec does not indicate what should be done with a `null` input, which means you have had to make a decision, and that decision should be documented. The 'easy' (and often best) option is to explicitly test for a `null` input and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` exception, so that anyone using your method receives a useful error message. You could argue that your code should do nothing with a `null`, but that's a bit iffy, because the spec doesn't qualify the behaviour, and that would 'silently' fail if someone passed it a `null` incorrectly: throwing an exception forces any unexpected usage to be address directly, which may or may not prompt a decision change, which makes it a good 'default' choice.

---

There is no need here to pre-declare `t`: just declare and assign it in one go:

```
T t = list.get(0);
```

This makes it easier to find out what it means. You could also make it `final` in this case, so that it is entirely clear that it is only assigned once, which makes it that little bit easier to reason about the code.

---

When writing recursive code like this, it can pay select the 'most ideal' base case. In this instance, any list of length no more than 1 is already reversed, so you could change the `if` condition to `list.size() > 1`. This doesn't change the complexity, but is something of which to be aware.

Answer (score 1):

Already answered, but as *task*, one probably fares better with not introducing too many extra structures.

I'll immediately give an iterative version. It shows some improvements that could also be made to your recursive solution.

The recursive solution is fine, though seemingly needing a call stack the size of the list. However tail-recursion can be optimized by a good compiler (made iterative).
The iterative version needs an extra variable to hold a temporary result (the recursive call's result).

```
public static <T> void reverse(List<T> list) {
    if (list.size() > 1) { // Not needed, heuristic optimisation
        //List<T> reversed = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
        List<T> reversed = new LinkedList<>();
        while (!list.isEmpty()) { // Or list.size() > 1
            T t = list.remove(0);
            reversed.add(t);
        }
        list.addAll(reversed);
    }
}
```

> I want to know if this is an efficient way of reversing a list

Already answered by others, but it could be astonishly good.
Nicer would be if the `list` was not modified *in-situ*, but substituted by a new List,
as then the `list.addAll(reversed)` could be exchanged for `return reversed;`.

> Is this working for every list as input?

Yes, though the list must not be operated upon at the same time.

There are some lists, immutable lists (that are not allowed to be changed) or lists that are backed by arrays (strudcturally immutable), that will throw an error.